# How to make slide toggle on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently doing responsive design for the website using `media queries` with `(max-width: 480px)`. Now, I have an issue of making `slideToggle` on `jQuery` from left to right. Basically, I'm adding class to element by using jQuery and styling this in `CSS`. However, I might assume there are other ways to make it...
But this is my approach. Please guys help me out, maybe you have some other recommendations how to solve this.

So, here is my `html`:

```
     <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><a href="/">Sport-concept.ru - интернет-магазин спортивных товаров</a></div>
    <div class="contacts">
      <p class="phone">+7(499)394-46-03<br />
+7(985)427-48-55<br />
 </p>
      <a id="js-close" class="js-close"></a>
      <p class="email"><a href="mailto:sport-concept@yandex.ru">sport-concept@yandex.ru</a></p>
    </div>
        <a id='js-phone' class='js-phone'></a>
        <a id="js-cart" class="js-cart" href="/basket"></a>
        <a id='js-mnu' class='js-mnu'></a>
        <a id="js-cat" class="js-cat"></a>
    <div class="mainmenu">
        <a id='js-cross' class='js-cross'></a>
      <ul>

                <li><a href="/" ><span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/menu/16" ><span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/menu/3" ><span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/menu/5" ><span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/articles" ><span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/menu/21" ><span></span></a></li>
                <li><a href="/menu/22" ><span></span></a></li>      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is `CSS`

```
#js-close {display:block;display:none;width:35px;height:35px;margin:17px  10px; position: absolute;
right: 0;}
.js-close{background:url(images/close-icon.png) center center no-repeat; opacity: 0.75; }
```

and this is `media`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
p.phone._opened {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

And my jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#js-phone").click(function(){
       $('p.phone').addClass("_opened");
    });
    $("js-close").click(function(){
        $('p_phone').removeClass("_opened");    
    });
});
```

Comment: Please share the full code you are trying

Comment: @SahilDhir Here is full code of what I'm trying to do

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use  `style='display:none'` for first load. And After Link click show your `div` and add class using `addClass`.

```js
$("#js-phone").click(function() {
 $('.contacts').show();
  $('p.phone').addClass("_opened");
});
$(".js-close").click(function() {
  $('.contacts').hide();
  $('p_phone').removeClass("_opened");
});
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  p.phone._opened {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header" >
  <div class="logo" ><a href="/">Sport-concept.ru - интернет-магазин спортивных товаров</a></div>
  <div class="contacts" style='display:none'>
    <p class="phone">+7(499)394-46-03<br /> +7(985)427-48-55
      <br />
    </p>
    <a id="js-close" class="js-close">Close</a>
    <p class="email"><a href="mailto:sport-concept@yandex.ru">sport-concept@yandex.ru</a></p>
  </div>
  <a id='js-phone' class='js-phone'>Phone</a>
  <a id="js-cart" class="js-cart" href="/basket">2</a>
  <a id='js-mnu' class='js-mnu'>3</a>
  <a id="js-cat" class="js-cat">4</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some problems with your code .

1. in JQ you are not writing the selectors correctly ( `js-close` needs to have `#` before it , and `p_phone` needs to be `p.phone` instead )
2. in CSS you need to hide your p.phone with `transform:translateX(-100%)` and then show it when has class `opened` with `transform:translateX(0%)` . Also add `transition` to the `p.phone` so when you close it , it will have transition

check snippet below ( Open = open button , Close = close button )

i changed the JQ a bit so it's more readable and easier to change, using selector caching ( the variables ) and event targeting. hope you don't mind

P.S i removed the media query so it will work in the snippet .

check fiddle with media query > [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jj6xzrwk/1)

```js
var open = $("#js-phone"),
    close = $("#js-close"),
    phone = $('p.phone')
$("body").on("click", function(e) {
  var target = $(e.target)
  if (target.is(open)) {
    $(phone).addClass("opened")
  }
  if (target.is(close)) {
    $(phone).removeClass("opened")
  }
})
```

```css
p.phone {
  transform: translateX(-120%);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.contacts {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

/*@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {*/
  p.phone.opened {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
/*}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"><a href="/">Sport-concept.ru - интернет-магазин спортивных товаров</a></div>
  <div class="contacts">
    <p class="phone">+7(499)394-46-03
      <br /> +7(985)427-48-55
      <br />
    </p>
    <a id="js-close" class="js-close">Close</a>
    <p class="email"><a href="mailto:sport-concept@yandex.ru">sport-concept@yandex.ru</a></p>
  </div>
  <a id='js-phone' class='js-phone'>Open</a>
  <a id="js-cart" class="js-cart" href="/basket"></a>
  <a id='js-mnu' class='js-mnu'></a>
  <a id="js-cat" class="js-cat"></a>
  <div class="mainmenu">
    <a id='js-cross' class='js-cross'></a>
    <ul>

      <li><a href="/"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu/16"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu/3"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu/5"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/articles"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu/21"><span></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="/menu/22"><span></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```